# Forgot if said birkas hamazon [bentching]

Tags: bentching

I was thinking that you would have to say it, since it's sofek d'oraisah.

But then you there is a sofek d'oraisah of bracha l'vatallah and we have a rule of sofek brochos l'kullah.

Anyone have sources for this sheillah.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%93_%D7%93

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering why sofek bracha l'vatallah doesn't override?

Comment: Probably bc that's likely not a deorayta issue. Is your question here about what the rule is or why the rule is?